# How to access Flutter Widget from another class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 classes and in my first class I want to display a widget from my second class.
I already tried to create in my first class an instance of second class and to use that instance to access the widget, but is not working.
Does anyone know how can I do this ?

Here is my demo code:

```
class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    const FirstScreen({Key? key}): super(key: key);

    @override
    State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return displayMainSection();
  }

  Widget displayMainSection() {

        return SecondScreen().someUsefulWidget(); // ERROR
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    const SecondScreen({Key? key}): super(key: key);

    @override
    State<SecondScreen> createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {

    Widget someUsefulWidget() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading this !

Answer (score 1):

But your coding is working fine. Here is a code where I created a red container from second class function:

```
class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: displayMainSection());
  }

  Widget displayMainSection() {
    return const SecondScreen().someUsefulWidget(); // ERROR
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondScreen({super.key});
  Widget someUsefulWidget() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right ! My code is working. I restarted my iMac and the simulator and now is randering fine. Thank you for enlightening me !